# Unable to see textview widget on screen when i write code in java?

Tags: java, android

Unable to see textview widget on screen when i write code in java

```
**@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)   {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ConstraintLayout Layout=new ConstraintLayout(this);
    Button bt=new Button(this);
    TextView tv=new TextView(this);
    Layout.addView(bt);
    Layout.addView(tv);
    setContentView(Layout);
}}**
```

Comment: It is invisible because it has no content do this `tv.setText("blah blah");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a view by calling its constructor and passing only a `Context` object, you're going to get the simplest default version of that view. A default `TextView` has no text, and is therefore invisible for all intents and purposes. To be able to see it, you will have to do *something* that makes it visible, like add text or define a width + add a background color.

You can see the `Button` because a default button has a **minimum width** and a **background** applied by default.